# Let $f:Q\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Then $f$ is integrable over Q if and only if give $\varepsilon>0$, there is $ \delta>0$ such that

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $f:Q\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Then $f$ is integrable over Q if and only if give $\varepsilon>0$, there is $ \delta>0$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)< \varepsilon$ for every partition $P$ of mesh less than $\delta$.

The proof of this is not immediately followed by the criterion of integrability?

Comment: How would you define a partition of $\Bbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: What is this $Q?$

Comment: @zhw.      Q is a compact set

Comment: Arbitrary compact set? Does "integrable" mean "Riemann integrable"?

Comment: @rdias It is not from $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @zhw. 
Yes it is

Comment: What is the definition of integrability in this setting?

Comment: @zhw. given $\varepsilon>0$ , There is a partition $P$ of $Q$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\varepsilon$

Comment: What is a partition of an arbitrary compact set?

Comment: @zhw. I do not think I can explain it very well, so it's better that you see "analysis on manifold" by Munkres 
In the part of Riemann integral.